# Print all the variables with NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to print usernames taken from one table and processes from another table and coonect them with one table. However not all the names have processes, so i need to print `NULL` or just empty space in processes column.

Here is sql i am using:

```
SELECT projectNo,
    proc_leader,
    group_concat(process) AS processes
FROM proc_leader
INNER JOIN user ON user.username = proc_leader.proc_leader
GROUP BY proc_leader,
    projectNo;
```

## EDIT

OK, what i want is to display all usernames and assigned processes for each username. For example, something like this:

```
username|      processes   | projectNo | 
--------+------------------+-----------+
barikan | ANM BLD, BGD CUP | 16001     |
beny    | BGD              | 16003     |
aaron   | NULL             | NULL      |
alon    | NULL             | NULL      |
candy   | BLD FCP          | 16003     |
```

What i got after using sql:

```
SELECT projectNo,
proc_leader,
group_concat(process) AS processes
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN proc_leader ON user.username = proc_leader.proc_leader
GROUP BY proc_leader, projectNo;
```

is [image: this]

It gives me only names with processes, but how to get all the nmaes? Thanks

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AFTER YOUR EDIT**

You have to print user.username and not proc_leader column ! Because you are getting all users, even if no proc_leader is associated, so if you print the proc_leader, you'll not see all users.

```
SELECT projectNo, username, group_concat(process) AS processes
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN proc_leader ON user.username = proc_leader.proc_leader
GROUP BY username, projectNo;
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

I don't truely understand your need, but remember that when you do a INNER JOIN on user.username, you only get the username that have a correspondence on proc_leader.

So if you want to display NULL username or Empty one from [Table 1], you need to do a **LEFT JOIN** instead. (aka LEFT OUTER JOIN)

More information : [image: Left Join Chart]
It took all rows from A, even without occurence on B.

Comment: it is an example on how I want to look it like, and below is what I actualy got when using LEFT JOIN

Comment: Yeah sorry, I saw it after. I edited my command, you need to select username, not proc_leader at the beginning

Comment: Oh, i see, thank you, cant upvote cuz not enough reputation, thanks for an answer

Comment: No problem ! You can mark my post as the answer if it works, to close the thread  :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.
That way, you're returning all the users and for each user without a process associated, it'll give you null values on the process column.

```
SELECT projectNo,
proc_leader,
group_concat(process) AS processes
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN proc_leader ON user.username = proc_leader.proc_leader
GROUP BY proc_leader, projectNo;
```

Also, the "FROM" table will have to be the users table, which is the table you want all values to be returned.

Comment: it gaves me just NULL on first row and then only names with proceses, see edit please

Comment: Isn't it amazing duplicate answers are in more interaction than original one, please try to give a distinct answers if possible, though you are collecting good score from dup ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use LEFT JOIN for that case

```
SELECT projectNo,
    proc_leader,
    group_concat(process) AS processes
FROM user
LEFT JOIN proc_leader ON user.username = proc_leader.proc_leader
GROUP BY proc_leader, projectNo;
```

I hope, the process column is exist in the proc_leader if not so then swap the table names.

Comment: Stil getting only names with processes, can view my edit, thank you

Comment: @Yevgeniy blank row doesn't make any sense there because in which basis we fetch the record from that child table even when proc_leader is also blank.

Comment: I changed proc_leader to username and now it's showing the way i want. Thanks